# Selecting records by latest date

Tags: sql-server

I am struggling to form a query that returns the latest records for different types of object. I have created the following example that shows what I am trying to achieve.

**Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE Fruit
(
    ID   [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Bites
(
    ID       [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    FruitID  [int] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Fruit(ID) NOT NULL,
    BittenOn [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

Now populate some test data.

```
INSERT INTO Fruit VALUES ( 'Apple' );
INSERT INTO Fruit VALUES ( 'Orange' );
INSERT INTO Fruit VALUES ( 'Strawberry' );

INSERT INTO Bites VALUES ( 1, '2014/2/20 12:30:00' );
INSERT INTO Bites VALUES ( 2, '2014/2/20 12:31:00' );
INSERT INTO Bites VALUES ( 2, '2014/2/20 12:32:00' );
INSERT INTO Bites VALUES ( 3, '2014/2/20 12:33:00' );
INSERT INTO Bites VALUES ( 3, '2014/2/20 12:34:00' );
INSERT INTO Bites VALUES ( 3, '2014/2/20 12:35:00' );
INSERT INTO Bites VALUES ( 1, '2014/2/20 12:40:00' );
INSERT INTO Bites VALUES ( 3, '2014/2/20 12:40:00' );
```

I would like my query to return the latest date each fruit was bitten.
I tried the following:

```
SELECT
    F.Name,
    B.BittenOn as LastBittenOn
FROM
    Fruit as F
INNER JOIN
    Bites as B ON B.BittenOn = ( SELECT MAX(BittenOn) FROM Bites )AND B.FruitID=F.ID
```

But I only get Apple and Strawberry because they share the lastest bite date but I would also like Orange with the date/time '2014/2/20 12:32:00'.

Can someone help me with the required query ?

Andy

Comment: order by COLUMNNAME [DESC]

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
SELECT  f.Name,
        b.BittenOn
FROM    Fruit as F OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT  TOP 1 *
            FROM    Bites b
            WHERE   b.FruitID = f.ID
            ORDER BY b.BittenOn DESC
        ) b
```

Another option would be

```
;WITH BitesCTE AS (
        SELECT  FruitID,
                MAX(BittenOn) BittenOn
        FROM    Bites
        GROUP BY    FruitID
)
SELECT  f.Name,
        b.BittenOn
FROM    Fruit f LEFT JOIN
        BitesCTE b  ON  f.ID = b.FruitID
```

Comment: Your answer with the CTE does not produce the correct results.

Comment: The CTE name and table name are same (both are BITES) ,this is because the CTE won't work.Just Change the CTE name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    F.Name,
    B.BittenOn as LastBittenOn
FROM
    Fruit as F
INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY FruitID ORDER BY BittenOn DESC) AS row_num
            ,FruitID
            ,BittenOn
    FROM Bites
    ) B
    ON F.ID = B.FruitID
    AND B.row_num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be a variation of astanders answer above:

```
SELECT  f.Name,
        b.BittenOn
FROM    Fruit as F OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT  MAX(b.BittenOn) as BittenOn
            FROM    Bites b
            WHERE   b.FruitID = f.ID
            GROUP BY b.FruitID
        ) b
```

Depending on indices it might be faster as it removes a costly sort. When I ran the original and altered versions the execution plan suggested query costs of 14% vs 86% (relative to the batch) in favor of using `max()`.

Edit: another version giving different output as requested in comment:

```
SELECT LastBites.FruitID, Bites.ID 
FROM Bites
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT b.FruitID,  MAX(b.BittenOn) as BittenOn
    FROM Bites b
    GROUP BY b.FruitID
) LastBites ON Bites.BittenOn = LastBites.BittenOn AND Bites.FruitID = LastBites.FruitID
ORDER BY LastBites.FruitID ASC
```

Comment: @user3332755 Consider upvoting Astanders answer too as my answer just is a variation of his.

Comment: I apologise, what I really need from the result of the query is the ID of the latest records so in my example, I was hoping for the ID field of each fruit with the ID of the latest bites record for that fruit so something like 1,7 ; 2,3 and 3,8.